# Kivy Installation via Makefile

Tags: python, linux, kivy

I'm tearing what's left of my hair out trying to figure out how to install Kivy on Linux. I'm a newb to pretty much everything, so not incredibly surprising, but I'm trying to make a Makefile that will install the necessary dependencies for my app that I build via Kivy.

This is my Makefile:

```
#!/bin/sh
all: packages program

packages:
    sudo apt-get install python3-kivy
    sudo apt-get install python3-pip
    sudo apt-get install python-setuptools python-dev build-essential 
    sudo apt-get install python3-dev
    sudo apt-get docutils-doc python3-pygame python-pil-doc python3-pil-dbg ttf-bitstream-vera
    sudo easy_install pip
    sudo apt-get -f install
    pip install --upgrade pip
    pip3 install python3-weather-api
    sudo pip install requests
    pip3 install beautifulsoup4
    pip3 install Cython
    pip3 install h5py
    pip3 install kivy

program: 
    python3 project.py
```

This is the output:

```
 sudo apt-get install python3-kivy
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree
    Reading state information... Done
    python3-kivy is already the newest version (1.10.0-0~stable0+201708191146~pkg175~ubuntu16.04.1).
    You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
    The following packages have unmet dependencies:
     python3-kivy : Depends: python3-kivy-common (= 1.10.0-0~stable0+201708191146~pkg175~ubuntu16.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: python3-kivy-bin (= 1.10.0-0~stable0+201708191146~pkg175~ubuntu16.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
    E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
    Makefile:5: recipe for target 'packages' failed
```

It keeps saying to run `apt-get -f install`, which I did, but the same error keeps popping up.

Comment: refer their installation guide : https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-linux.html

Comment: Thanks - tried those, but same error - no luck unfortunately. I don't know enough about it, but is my shebang line correct?

Comment: Could you state your setup (Linux flavour and version)

Comment: This is through Bash on Ubuntu on Windows...
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial

Comment: The problem is with the order and selection of your packages. Like, you need to install a compatible version of Cython before installing Kivy. Please follow the official doc and then reshape your Makefile.